# Символы Unicode в smatch (regex)

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, unicode

Использую обычные библиотеки string и regex, понадобилось написать приложение которое парсит строки регулярками, массив найденных значений удивил... Написал код для чистого тестирования:

```
string str = "конечно";
cout << str << endl;
regex re("([А-я]+)");
smatch sm;
regex_search(str, sm, re);
cout << sm[0] << endl;
```

Вывод:

```
конечно
коне\321
```

Как избавиться от символов юникода?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/non_std_strings/icu/unicode_algo.html, обычный regex похоже не умеет с utf работать, еще можно пробовать конветрировать это все в wstring

Comment: Используйте версии `wstring`, `wregex`, `wsmatch`, `wcout`, возможно `SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); SetConsoleCP(1251);`. В какой среде выполняется код?

Answer (score 1):

Regex не умеет работать с Кириллицей. Первые 3 символа были обработаны, так как коне - в том числе латинские буквы. Для работы с ней необходимо использовать boost или пользоваться локалями (koi8-r, cp1251 ,ibm866) [stackoverflow (тык)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/786964/regex-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0).

Таким образом работать с кириллицей, так же просто, как с латиницей пока не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str = "конечно";
    std::cout << str << '\n';
    std::regex re("([абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя]+)");
    std::smatch sm;
    std::regex_search(str, sm, re);
    std::cout << sm[0] << '\n';
}
```